# How to split through the whole list using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint

In my CSV file I have "SharePoint Site" column and a few other columns. I'm trying to split the ID from "SharePoint Site" columns and put it to the new column call "SharePoint ID" but not sure how to do it so I'll be really appreciated If I can get any help or suggestion.

```
$downloadFile = Import-Csv "C:\AuditLogSearch\New folder\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv"

(($downloadFile -split "/") -split "_") | Select-Object -Index 5
```

CSV file

```
SharePoint Site
Include:[https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/elksn7_nam_corp_kl_com]
Include:[https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/tzksn_nam_corp_kl_com]
Include:[https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/msteams_c578f2/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2Fmsteams%5Fc578f2%2FShared%20Documents%2FBittner%2DWilfong%20%2D%20Litigation%20Hold%2FWork%20History&viewid=b3e993a1%2De0dc%2D4d33%2D8220%2D5dd778853184]
Include:[https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/msteams_c578f2/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2Fmsteams%5Fc578f2%2FShared%20Documents%2FBittner%2DWilfong%20%2D%20Litigation%20Hold%2FWork%20History&viewid=b3e993a1%2De0dc%2D4d33%2D8220%2D5dd778853184]
Include:[All]
```

After spliting this will show it under new Column call "SharePoint ID"

```
SharePoint ID
2. elksn
3. tzksn
4. msteams_c578f2
5. msteams_c578f2
6. All
```

Comment: Please do not use the Excel tag for CSV files. Excel is not CSV. The extension on your file is not .xls or .xlsx, it is .csv, which is a good clue.

Comment: Do you mean an *additional* column or just this column?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Import csv into an array
$Sites = (Import-Csv C:\temp\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv).'SharePoint Site'

# Create Export variable
$Export = @()

# ForEach loop that goes through the SharePoint sites one at a time
ForEach($Site in $Sites){
    
    # Clean up the input to leave only the hyperlink
    $Site = $Site.replace('Include:[','')
    $Site = $Site.replace(']','')

    # Split the hyperlink at the fifth slash (Split uses binary, so 0 would be the first slash)

    $SiteID = $Site.split('/')[4]

    # The 'SharePoint Site' Include:[All] entry will be empty after doing the split, because it has no 4th slash.
    # This If statement will detect if the $Site is 'All' and set the $SiteID as that.

    if($Site -eq 'All'){
        $SiteID = $Site
    }

    # Create variable to export Site ID
    $SiteExport = @()
    $SiteExport = [pscustomobject]@{
        'SharePoint ID' = $SiteID
    }
    
    # Add each SiteExport to the Export array
    $Export += $SiteExport
}

# Write out the export
$Export
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 distinct patterns you are trying to extract data from. I believe regex would be an appropriate tool.

If you are wanting the new csv to just have the single ID column.

```
$file = "C:\AuditLogSearch\New folder\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv"

$IdList = switch -Regex -File ($file){
    'Include:.+(?=/(\w+?)_)(?<=personal)' {$matches.1}
    'Include:(?=\[(\w+)\])' {$matches.1}
    'Include:.+(?=/(\w+?)/)(?<=sites)' {$matches.1}
}

$IdList |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "Sharepoint ID" |
        Export-Csv -Path $newfile -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to add a column to your existing CSV

```
$file = "C:\AuditLogSearch\New folder\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv"

$properties = ‘*’,@{
    Name = 'Sharepoint ID'
    Expression = {
        switch -Regex ($_.'sharepoint Site'){
            'Include:.+(?=/(\w+?)_)(?<=personal)' {$matches.1}
            'Include:(?=\[(\w+)\])' {$matches.1}
            'Include:.+(?=/(\w+?)/)(?<=sites)' {$matches.1}
        }
    }
}

Import-Csv -Path $file |
    Select-Object $properties |
        Export-Csv -Path $newfile -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Regex details**

- `.+`       Match any amount of any character
- `(?=...)`  Positive look ahead
- `(...)`    Capture group
- `\w+`      Match one or more word characters
- `?`        Lazy quantifier
- `(?<=...)` Positive look behind

Comment: Hi @DougMaurer, Thank you so much for this but just wondering how can I arrange new column order with my existing columns?. Right now the new column "Sharepoint Id" is always at the begining and I don't want that to be at the begining.

Answer (score 1):

This would require more testing to see if it works well, but with the input we have *it works*, the main concept is to use [`System.Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-6.0) to parse the strings. From what I'm seeing, the segment you are looking for is always the third one `[2]` and depending on the previous segments, perform a split on `_` or trim the trailing `/` or leave the string *as is* if `IsAbsoluteUri` is `$false`.

```
$csv = Import-Csv path/to/test.csv

$result = foreach($line in $csv)
{
    $uri = [uri]($line.'SharePoint Site' -replace '^Include:\[|]$')
    
    $id = switch($uri)
    {
        {-not $_.IsAbsoluteUri} {
            $_
            break
        }
        { $_.Segments[1] -eq 'personal/' } {
            $_.Segments[2].Split('_')[0]
            break
        }
        { $_.Segments[1] -eq 'sites/' } {
            $_.Segments[2].TrimEnd('/')
        }
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        'SharePoint Site' = $line.'SharePoint Site'
        'SharePoint ID'   = $id 
    }
}

$result | Format-List
```

Answer (score 1):

A concise solution that appends a `Sharepoint ID` column to the existing columns by way of a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```sh
Import-Csv 'C:\AuditLogSearch\New folder\Modified-Audit-Log-Records.csv' | 
  Select-Object *, @{
    Name = 'SharePoint ID'
    Expression = {
      $tokens = $_.'SharePoint Site' -split '[][/]'
      if ($tokens.Count -eq 3) { $tokens[1] } # matches 'Include:[All]'
      else                     { $tokens[5] -replace '_nam_corp_kl_com$' }
    }
  }
```

Note:

- To see all resulting column values, pipe the above to [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list).
- To re-export the results to a CSV file, pipe to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)